# ESP HTTP connection issue : on connection callback function not getting called

Tags: http, lua, dns, wifi, nodemcu

I am using custom build for NodeMCU with following modules: cjson, file, gpio, http, net, node, ow, tmr, websocket, wifi.

```
conn = nil
conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP)      -- 30 seconds timeout time of serv

conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload)
        print("Server DB Connected, sending event")   -- This line is not getting print on esplorer. 
        conn:send ( <some-data>)
end)

conn:connect(80,"mysite.com")
conn:close()
```

For debugging i tried using following code :

```
net.dns.resolve("www.google.com", function(sk, ip)
if (ip == nil) then
print("DNS fail!")
else 
print("Resolved: " .. ip) 
end
end)
```

But above is giving output " DNS fail! "

Site is working perfectly fine along with server.
A normal GET request to the same site using putty is returning correct data.

Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: If DNS fails it's highly likely that your WiFi connection wasn't set up properly.

Comment: No wifi connection is proper. I'm doing =wifi.sta.status() at that point of time, and getting output "5" . Also i'm getting the correct IP address for my ESP.
I also tried to do a bit of google, some also suggests that it Firewall may be blocking the connection. But that's also voided. 
Also i'm assuming, dns module is already in custom wifi module build, because i'm not getting any error if i remove the dns.resolve statement (although still on-connection isn't working).

Also, conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP) seems working... so no issue with ESP to router/internet connection

Comment: Again, if DNS resolution fails `conn:connect(80,"mysite.com")` is unlikely to succeed unless you use the IP instead of `mysite.com`. "conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP) seems working" - this doesn't mean much as this involve little to no networking operations, it just creates a connection object. Furthermore, by calling `conn:close()` immediately after `conn:connect` you're likely closing the connection before anything was sent at all (only close when done sending). See https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend

Comment: Also check what `net.dns.getdnsserver()` returns: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netdnsgetdnsserver

Comment: Thanks @MarcelStör for providing the detailed info to laymen like me. 
So what do you suggest to resolve / debug the issue further ?
Because wifi.sta.status() returns 5, but dns isn't resolving. What can cause the wifi connection issue ?